# Real time settings changes

Tags: android, service, settings

please how to propagate settings changes into running service? Does android have some callback for this? I have my own settings in sharedpreferences so I don't think so... What is usual way how to do that? 
For example disable background data sending from the service. 
I mean my own custom settings..Not global phone preferences

Comment: there is a listener mechanism for sharedpreferences

Answer (score 0):

If by "settings" you mean the Settings application, some of those have associated broadcast `Intents`, such as  [`ACTION_BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#ACTION_BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED) for "disable background data sending from the service".

Comment: As of Ice Cream Sandwich the ACTION_BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGE constant is deprecated.